# spyOn not working for calling the function multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using NgbModal in my components and i am trying to write test case for that component.

My component function where i have opened modal look like this:

```js
cancelLicense(activeMiningLicensesName: string, subscriptionId: string) {
    const dialogueComponent: any = this.modalService.open(DialogueComponent, {
      size: "md" as "lg",
      centered: true,
      backdrop: "static",
      keyboard: false,
    });
    console.log(dialogueComponent, "===========================>");
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.message = `Are you sure you want to cancel your weekly subscription for ${activeMiningLicensesName}?`;
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.confirmText = "Yes";
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.cancelText = "No";
    dialogueComponent.result.then((isConfirmClicked) => {
      if (isConfirmClicked) {
        this.confirmCancelLicense(activeMiningLicensesName, subscriptionId);
      }
    });
  }

  confirmCancelLicense(activeMiningLicensesName: string, subscriptionId: string) {
    const dialogueComponent: any = this.modalService.open(DialogueComponent, {
      size: "md" as "lg",
      centered: true,
      backdrop: "static",
      keyboard: false,
    });
    console.log("----------------------->3", dialogueComponent);
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.message = `Please note that once you cancel, you can not get a refund unless the request for a refund falls within thirty (30) days of purchase. Also, refund only applies to the Yearly subscriptions; for more details, refer to the Terms and Conditions. Cancel anyway?`;
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.confirmText = "Yes";
    dialogueComponent.componentInstance.cancelText = "No";
    dialogueComponent.result.then((isConfirmClicked) => {
      console.log("----------------------->2");
      if (isConfirmClicked) {
        this.subscriptionCancellation(activeMiningLicensesName, subscriptionId);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here modelService is an injector to NgbModal service.

Now coming to test case, I have mocked modelService like below:

```js
modalService = TestBed.inject(NgbModal);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
const ngBmodalref: Partial < NgbModalRef > = {
  componentInstance: {},
  result: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
      status: true
    });
  }),
};
modelOpenSpy = spyOn(modalService, "open").and.returnValue(ngBmodalref as NgbModalRef);
```

Everything works fine when the model.open function is called in test case for the first time but when it is called second time rather than returning spied value it returns a NgBModalRefrence(see attached image)

[image]

If anyone can help me figure out why this is happening!

Note: I also tried spyOn().and.returnValues() and passing two different value, then also it is working the same way.

Here is the testcase for the issue:

```js
it("should allow user to cancel its licenses", () => {
  spyOn(somaService, "checkNodeOprator").and.returnValue( of (holderInformationMock));
  const subscriptionCancelSpy = spyOn(accountinformationservice, "subscriptionCancellation").and.returnValue( of ({
    status: 200
  }));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const purchasedLicensesTab = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("#purchased-licenses-tab");
  purchasedLicensesTab.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const cancelLicenseButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("#cancel-license-button");
  cancelLicenseButton.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(modelOpenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  expect(subscriptionCancelSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here cancelLicenses function is called when the cancelLicensesButton is clicked!

Comment: could you also provide code of your test and probably beforeEach and beforeAll

Comment: @Andrei I have updated the code with the testcase and i am not using any beforeAll and beforeeach is the part where i have spied on model

Comment: it seems your promises are resolved after the test had ended. try make the test async and `await fixture.whenStable()`

Comment: Thanks Andrei!
You were right, waiting for the fixture to get stable worked for me!